# "... if he do not turn disciple" - an error in the poem? Should be "does not"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

From "[Prometheus in Straits](http://apoemaday.tumblr.com/post/19736086977/prometheus-in-straits)" by J.C. Ransom:

> Though I be Prometheus my wits wandered
>   To bring my pious offices unto this people.
>   Where all must be the teachers nullity is engendered,
>   My doctrine perishes crying for an ear that is simple,
>   The prophet is solicited before he has well thundered
>   And escapes with credit if he ***do not*** turn disciple.

Isn't there an error? Shouldn't it read thus instead:

> And escapes with credit if he **does not** turn disciple.

Comment: This is a good question, though it should be noted that this poem is written using slightly archaic grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This poem is written in a very old style of English that is no longer grammatically valid in Standard English. This is apparent right from the very first line, where the author says "Though I ***be*** Prometheus", which is an obsolete construction meaning "(Al)Though I **am** Prometheus".

In modern use, ***he do not turn disciple*** is not correct; *if he do not* should be *If he does not*.

A modern equivalent of the final line would then be:

> ... and escapes with credit ***if he does not become a disciple***.

Comment: @snailboat: You are, of course, correct. Turned <noun> is fairly unusual in colloquial English; "Turned into a <noun>" is much more common.

Comment: Although it does survive in expressions such as *turned traitor*.